# jquery show division when click on li

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to do some animation when i click on li particular division should active.
i have tried    this however i not able to show particular division when i click on li

this is my jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.clients-list li').click(function(){

 $('.clients-list li').removeClass('active');

$(this).addClass('active');

});

});
```

this is my structure of ul

```
      <ul class="clients-list" role="tablist">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#client-01"><img src="images/demo-images/clients/client.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#client-02"><img src="images/demo-images/clients/client2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#client-03"><img src="images/demo-images/clients/client3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>


                  <div class="client-testimonials-list">
                            <div id="client-01" class="single-testimonial tab-pane fade in active">
                                <h2>The Perfect Design theme is really amazing!</h2>
                                <p>Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks. Dynamically procrastinate B2C users after installed base benefits. Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without revolutionary ROI. Efficiently unleash cross-media information without cross-media value. Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time schemas. </p>

                                <div class="client-info">
                                    <h2>Jennifer Toyen</h2>
                                    <p>Artist</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="client-02" class="single-testimonial tab-pane fade in">
                                <h2>Use lap as chair destroy couch but rub face</h2>
                                <p>Use lap as chair destroy couch but rub face on everything for play time. Give attitude why must they do that yet stare at ceiling but hide when guests come over hunt anything that moves play time. Sweet beast stick butt in face yet flop over but flop over for hopped up on goofballs. Stare at ceiling stick butt in face and leave dead animals as gifts and missing until dinner time. Sweet beast sweet beast shake treat bag yet play time mark territory why must they do that. </p>

                                <div class="client-info">
                                    <h2>Client Name two</h2>
                                    <p>CTO, Company Name, TX</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
```

Comment: Try with `$('.client-testimonials-list').addClass('active');` instead of `this`. `this` will point to the document here.

Answer (score 0):

I had two browser tabs open so I was answering the wrong question, sorry about that :)